# convert form application to wpf application makes an error

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi i have an application that is programmed by c# windows form and works great .i move all codes of this application to wpf project but a function in wpf have an error

I declare this function as you ca see :

```
 [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("MNPR.dll")]
 unsafe private static extern int LP_Initialize(char* security_code, byte log_level, IntPtr hwndMsg);
```

and call this here

```
 public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            unsafe
            {
                string security_code = "TSF";
                char[] security_code_p = new char[40];
                for (int i = 0; i < security_code.Length; i++)
                    security_code_p[i] = security_code[i];
                fixed (char* p = &security_code_p[0])
                {
                    LP_Initialize(p, 1, Handle);
                }
            }

            LP_SetParams(10, 7, 20, 15, 1100, show_car_image ? (byte)2 : (byte)1, 0);

        }
```

I move all these code to wpf project as you can see:

```
  public MainViewModel()
        {

            string publicKey = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>\r\n<RSAParameters xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">\r\n  <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>\r\n  <Modulus>x2U1misu3xXuLCAf79dVzUc8b1XcRJUL24gSSc41i2sY5c7nI7s5XUceuMU0o7YwHaLEp2upRI9B8PWAQzIeumFGxnui4sdJBTcY9loP7/+N85PL5MWuxBn6e3ejjwTQUEZ0QS7CgJk8jyF4Ae2M/bpWED6ZHmNs2PgYnHNQEqv3Zb5kuof4JL1C+rK9qnT5HNreF/N322uE7HbazZIPGqCnO4bO4RQupd15ztV8O4S7g5dtSucG7AxYbRl+RpxXZA1GQy2dA29wA8kaFtFoe0D4DCF+Ohfg+ySMdgZSw2BRqkOQc+r5I4ETo4KA+/9Yrm4IdHk++KxWQ5CwapRgIQ==</Modulus>\r\n</RSAParameters>";
            secureString = Utility.ConvertToSecureString(publicKey);
            publicKey = string.Empty;
            timerCallWS = new System.Timers.Timer(30000);
            this.timerCallWS.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this.timerCallWS_Tick);

            NewCarReceiption = new MainModel();
            SaveCommand = new MCR.Commands.RelayCommand(Save, CanSave);
            ClearCommand = new MCR.Commands.RelayCommand(Clear);
            CaptureCommand = new MCR.Commands.RelayCommand(Capture);
            PreviewCommand = new Commands.RelayCommand(Preview);
            WindowLoadEvent = new DelegateCommand<object>(Load);
            CancelAsyncCommand = new MCR.Commands.RelayCommand(CancelAsync);
            IncorrectRecognitionCommand = new MCR.Commands.RelayCommand(IncorrectRecognition);
            CorrectRecognitionCommand = new MCR.Commands.RelayCommand(CorrectRecognition);
            cmbVehicleTypeChangedEvent = new DelegateCommand<object>(VehicleTypeChangedEvent);
            cmbVehicleSystemChangedEvent = new DelegateCommand<object>(VehicleSystemChangedEvent);
            controlGotFocusEvent = new DelegateCommand<object>(ControlGotFocusEvent);

            this.PLQRecognitionBtnVisibilityStatus = false;
            CancelAsyncVisibility = false;
            MainWrapPanel = false;


            unsafe
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("HID = " + LP_GetHID().ToString());
                string security_code = "TSF";
                char[] security_code_p = new char[40];
                for (int i = 0; i < security_code.Length; i++)
                    security_code_p[i] = security_code[i];
                fixed (char* p = &security_code_p[0])
                {
                    LP_Initialize(p, 1,Handle);
                }
            }
            //it is not required to call LP_SetParams with default params, but if you want to change them, you must call it
            LP_SetParams(10, 7, 20, 15, 1100, show_car_image ? (byte)2 : (byte)1, 0);
            string info = "آستانه‏ی تشخیص ورود خودرو\n" +
    "برای تصاویر شب، مقدار 7 و برای روز مقدار 20 مناسب است\n" +
"مقدار بزرگتر حساسیت کمتری دارد و خودروی کمتری تشخیص می دهد";

        }
```

[image]

As you can see this part `LP_Initialize(p, 1,Handle);` `Handle`.what should i use instead of Handle in wpf?

Comment: Upvoted for user name alone. :)

Comment: @MichaelGunter :)))))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF doesn't provide direct access to the HWND like WinForms does. Getting it is not hard, though. From within your `Window` subclass, you can do something like:

```
IntPtr handle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
```

From within `UserControl` subclasses, you can do something like:

```
Window window = Window.GetWindow(this);
if (window == null)
{
    // The user control is not on a window.
    // Handle this situation as appropriate.
}
IntPtr handle = new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle;
```

Comment: I added Window window = Window.GetWindow(this);
if (window == null)
{
    // The user control is not on a window.
    // Handle this situation as appropriate.
}
IntPtr handle = new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle;   before LP_Initialize line but i get an error in "this" keyword :Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'MCR.ViewModel.MainViewModel' to 'System.Windows.DependencyObject'

Comment: Your view model is neither a `Window` subclass nor a `UserControl` subclass. If you need to execute `LP_Initialize` from your view model, you need to develop a way to get the handle (returned via the code above) from your view to your view model.

Comment: I added a function to my view as you can see     public IntPtr GetIntPtr()
        {
            Window window = Window.GetWindow(this);
            if (window == null)
            {
                // The user control is not on a window.
                // Handle this situation as appropriate.
            }
            IntPtr handle = new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle;
            return handle;
        },but how can i call this function in viewmodel?

Comment: could you please take a look at this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099803/an-unhandled-exception-of-type-system-stackoverflowexception-occurred-in-mscor