# Passing window handle to view model in WPF with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am using an external library which requires a window handle. My application architecture is MVVM, but the external library doesn't exactly fit into this architecture. I have decided that the view model is the most appropriate place to call an initialization function which requires a window handle. How can I get the window handle from my view to my view model?

Comment: @MichaelGunter i call my view inside the constructor of my viewmodel

Comment: @MichaelGunter as you know about the previous question i just want to get the handler of my windows ,and you said i have to create a function inside my view to return the value

Comment: May I edit your question in order to make it more precise? I can then provide a direct answer.

Comment: @MichaelGunter yes why not ,i will be appreciated

Comment: @MichaelGunter thank you Michael

Comment: `How can I get the window handle from my view to my view model?` That's not MVVM, so do it however you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically, your view model shouldn't know about the implementation details of your view (such as it's HWND). However, as your question indicates, the external library you are using requires you to initialize it, and you can only do that in one place. Assuming that your view model is the most appropriate place for it (it might even belong in the model), you can do something like the following.

This implementation provides the window handle to your view model as soon as all the pieces are available. Note that the view model implementation that you provided in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099194/convert-form-application-to-wpf-application-makes-an-error/43099411#43099411) requires the HWND in the view model's constructor. You're going to have to change your view model so that the initialization happens via an explicitly called method or property. In the code below, I assume that there is a method in your view model called `OnWindowHandleAvailable`. You could certainly call that method `Initialize` instead, or you could put a `Handle` property on your view model which you explicitly set.

```
public partial class View
{
    public View()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += View_Loaded;
        this.DataContextChanged += View_DataContextChanged;
    }

    private void View_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GiveWindowHandleToViewModel();
    }

    private void View_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        GiveWindowHandleToViewModel();
    }

    private void GiveWindowHandleToViewModel()
    {
        // get view model
        var viewModel = this.DataContext as ViewModel;
        if (viewModel == null)
            return;

        // get window handle
        var windowHandle = this.GetWindowHandle();
        if (windowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            return;

        // signal view model
        viewModel.OnWindowHandleAvailable(windowHandle);
    }

    private IntPtr GetWindowHandle()
    {
        // get window
        var window = Window.GetWindow(this);
        if (window == null)
            return IntPtr.Zero;

        // get window handle
        return new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle;
    }
}
```

Comment: As for where you create `ViewModel`, if you use the code I've given you above, you can create `ViewModel` in `View`'s constructor, or in `View_Loaded`, or somewhere entirely outside of `View`. Pure MVVM would have you create `ViewModel` somewhere outside of `View` and then set `view.DataContext` in that same location.

Comment: In this line var viewModel = this.DataContext as ViewModel; i get this  'ViewModel' is a namespace but is used like a type

Comment: I used `View` and `ViewModel` generically in this code. You'll have to plug in your specific class names.

Comment: I would just create view model constructor and replace all that stuff with `this.DataContext = new MyViewModel(this.GetWindowHandle());` after `InitializeComponent();`. What is the reason to complicate this so much?

Comment: @Kamil You won't be able to get the window handle in the constructor. `Window.GetWindow` will return `null` at that point in time. You can construct the view-model in the constructor, which will obviate the need for the `DataContextChanged` handler, but you still need the `Loaded` event handler.

Answer (score 2):

This can also be achieved without the View having access to the ViewModel by using a command.

In the View.xaml.cs

```cs
private void View_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the Window
    var win = WinTools.FindParentWindow(this);
    if (win != null)   // stops designer errors
    {
        var winHan = new WindowInteropHelper(win).Handle;
        // Execute the command with Window handle as parameter
        WinInfo?.Execute(winHan);   
    }
}

// Command Property
public ICommand WinInfo
{
    get => (ICommand)GetValue(WinInfoProperty);
    set => SetValue(WinInfoProperty, value);
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty WinInfoProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("WinInfo",
            typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(View));
```

In the xaml

```xml
<View WinInfo="{Binding WinInfoCmd}" />
```

And finally in the ViewModel.cs

```cs
private IntPtr _winHandle;

// setup to receive command
private RelayCommand _winInfoCmd;
public ICommand WinInfoCmd { get { return _winInfoCmd ??= new RelayCommand(o => SetWin((IntPtr)o), o => true); } }

private void SetWin(IntPtr han)
{
    _winHandle = han;
}
```